# Documents missing in Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search-engine

I am using elasticsearch `0.90.10`. Using mongodb river I indexed the documents from mongodb. The initial load and indexing are working fine. But after some time the count of documents starts decreasing gradually (losing the documents). I am using mongodb-river version `1.7.4`

These are the configs in my elasticsearch.yml.

## Cluster Properties

```
cluster.name: 192.168.31.50:9300
index.store.type: niofs
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
path.logs: /home/test/Test/scripts/../logs/search
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

## Search pool

```
threadpool.search.type: fixed
threadpool.search.size: 5
threadpool.search.queue_size: 200
```

## Bulk pool

```
threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 5
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 300
```

## Index pool

```
threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 5
threadpool.index.queue_size: 200
```

## Indices settings

```
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 12mb
indices.memory.min_index_buffer_size: 96mb
```

## Cache Sizes

```
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 15%
indices.fielddata.cache.expire: 6h
indices.cache.filter.size: 15%
indices.cache.filter.expire: 6h
```

## Indexing Settings for Writes

```
index.refresh_interval: 30s
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000
```

These configurations are causing document loss in my production environment. What can I do to pinpoint the exact problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @javanna please look into this and help me..!

Comment: I have the same issue with my jdbc-river. I'm not sure if it is related to the JVM heap size.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the ttl property being set?  That's the only thing I've ever heard of "removing" documents.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html

Comment: Definitely not..  I checked all possibilities :(